# Consumir servicios de API Node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, endpoint

Estimad@s, tengo un microservicio (a) o una pequeña API que requiere hacer uso de los servicios de otra API (b), que se compone de unos 4 ENDPOINT(Direccion, comuna, provincia, region, etc).

Actualmente utilizo un modulo de NODE que se llama request:

```
const request = require('request');
```

pero solamente puedo hacer llamado a un endpoint:

```
 request(
        `http://localhost:3000/v1/api/endpoint/${parametro_1}/? 
         parametroQuery=${parametroQuery}`,
        { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
          if (err) { return console.log(err); }
          if (body.data) {
            body.data.forEach((o) => {

            })
          }
        }
      );
```

Con los datos que obtengo, específicamente un id que me llega de ese endpoint, debo hacer el llamado a otro servicio, y así cerca de 4 servicios sucesivamente.

De qué forma me sugieren hacerlo para que sea más óptimo y eficiente?

Comment: Ya que NodeJS es de un solo hilo (Single Thread) te sugiero usando Promesas para no bloquear el runtime de node.

Answer (score 0):

Usando el módulo `request`, si cada petición necesita del valor de la anterior, cada nueva llamada la deberías hacerla en el callback de la anterior, pero en lugar de eso puedes usar promesas, con el modulo [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) y harías algo como:

```
var request = require('request-promise');

var url1 = "ejemplo1.com";
var url2 = "ejemplo2.com";
var url3 = "ejemplo3.com";

request(url1)
  .then(respuesta => {
    // respuesta de url1 y modifico url2
    return request(url2)
  })
  .then(respuesta => {
    // respuesta de url2 y modifico url3
    return request(url3)
  })
  .then(respuesta => {
    //luego de todas las respuestas
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a probar y te aviso como me va